# How to write a file comfortable and easy?

Tags: c#, file, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, filewriter

I'm pretty new in developing C#, and my problem is to write a text file. I found some solution with StreamWriter lik this...

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("C:\Downloads\test.txt");
file.WriteLine("this is line one");
file.WriteLine("\r\n");
file.WriteLine("this is line 2");
file.Close();
```

Is there a more comfortable way to write a file? Maybe without the hardcoded `"\r\n"`?

Comment: What do you mean by _comfortable_? Why do you think this is _uncomfortable_?

Comment: Just use [`file.WriteLine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebb1kw70(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `file.WriteLine("\r\n")`.

Comment: You should also use a 'using' statement as StreamWriter implements IDisposable.

Comment: Indeed - and this is only pseudo-code anyway, given that you don't actually have a string literal in the first line, and the call would be to `Close`, not `close`. It's helpful to put *real* code in a question rather than pseudo-code, where possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest approach for writing a multi-line file is [`File.WriteAllLines`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines):

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\Downloads\test.txt",
    new[] { "this is line one", "", "", "this is line 2" });
```

The empty strings are there because in your original code, you'd end with *four* lines of text... `WriteLine` already adds a line separator, and you've got one explicitly in the middle call too. If you only want two lines (as per the specified contents) then you should use:

```
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\Downloads\test.txt",
    new[] { "this is line one", "this is line 2" });
```

That will use the platform-default line ending. If you don't want to use that, you could use `string.Join` to join lines together however you want, then call [`File.WriteAllText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext).

All `File.*` methods dealing with text default to using UTF-8, but allow you to specify the encoding if you want something else.

Answer (score 1):

If your only concern is the line endings, you can use a single, empty `WriteLine()` (which uses `Environment.NewLine`, which takes the line end representation for that OS):

```
file.WriteLine();
```

Besides that, `StreamWriter` is a good way to write to a file, and it is pretty easy too. If you prefer long string concatenation and writing at once, `File.WriteAllText` is an option.

And don't forget the `using` statement to dispose your resources:

```
using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(C:\Downloads\test.txt))
{
    // ... your code
}
```